# How to compute average value for each year and month combinations using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 `numpy` `array`s, namely, `times` and `values`. (see below for reproducible data).

1. `times` contains dates (yyyy-mm-dd)
2. `values` contains values for each corresponding date

Now, I want to compute average value for each month and year combinations. For example, if there are 5 years of daily data I want to have a 5*12=60 values (e.g. something like 'group by year and month').

What is the best way to achieve this using `numpy`?

**Reproducible data**:

1. `times`

```
# import the numpy library
import numpy as np

times = np.array(['2004-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-04T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-05T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-06T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-07T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-08T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-10T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-11T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-12T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-13T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-14T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-15T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-17T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-18T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-19T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-20T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-21T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-22T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-24T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-25T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-26T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-27T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-28T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-29T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-01-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-01-31T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-02-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-02-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-02-03T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-02-04T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-02-05T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-02-06T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-02-07T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-02-08T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-02-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-02-10T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-02-11T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-02-12T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-02-13T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-02-14T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-02-15T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-02-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-02-17T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-02-18T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-02-19T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-02-20T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-02-21T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-02-22T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-02-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-02-24T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-02-25T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-02-26T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-02-27T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-02-28T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-02-29T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-03-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-03-04T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-05T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-03-06T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-07T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-03-08T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-03-10T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-11T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-03-12T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-13T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-03-14T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-15T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-03-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-17T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-03-18T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-19T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-03-20T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-21T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-03-22T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-03-24T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-25T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-03-26T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-27T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-03-28T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-29T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-03-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-03-31T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-04-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-04-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-04-03T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-04-04T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-04-05T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-04-06T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-04-07T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-04-08T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-04-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-04-10T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-04-11T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-04-12T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-04-13T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-04-14T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-04-15T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-04-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-04-17T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-04-18T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-04-19T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-04-20T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-04-21T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-04-22T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-04-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-04-24T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-04-25T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-04-26T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-04-27T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-04-28T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-04-29T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-04-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-05-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-03T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-05-04T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-05T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-05-06T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-07T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-05-08T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-05-10T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-11T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-05-12T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-13T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-05-14T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-15T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-05-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-17T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-05-18T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-19T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-05-20T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-21T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-05-22T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-05-24T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-25T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-05-26T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-27T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-05-28T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-29T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-05-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-05-31T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-06-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-06-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-06-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-06-04T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-06-05T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-06-06T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-06-07T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-06-08T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-06-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-06-10T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-06-11T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-06-12T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-06-13T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-06-14T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-06-15T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-06-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-06-17T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-06-18T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-06-19T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-06-20T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-06-21T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-06-22T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-06-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-06-24T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-06-25T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-06-26T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-06-27T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-06-28T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-06-29T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-06-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-07-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-07-04T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-05T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-07-06T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-07T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-07-08T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-07-10T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-11T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-07-12T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-13T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-07-14T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-15T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-07-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-17T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-07-18T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-19T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-07-20T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-21T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-07-22T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-07-24T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-25T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-07-26T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-27T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-07-28T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-29T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-07-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-07-31T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-08-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-03T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-08-04T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-05T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-08-06T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-07T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-08-08T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-08-10T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-11T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-08-12T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-13T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-08-14T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-15T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-08-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-17T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-08-18T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-19T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-08-20T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-21T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-08-22T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-08-24T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-25T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-08-26T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-27T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-08-28T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-29T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-08-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-08-31T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-09-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-09-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-09-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-09-04T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-09-05T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-09-06T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-09-07T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-09-08T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-09-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-09-10T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-09-11T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-09-12T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-09-13T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-09-14T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-09-15T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-09-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-09-17T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-09-18T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-09-19T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-09-20T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-09-21T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-09-22T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-09-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-09-24T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-09-25T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-09-26T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-09-27T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-09-28T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-09-29T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-09-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-10-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-10-04T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-05T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-10-06T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-07T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-10-08T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-10-10T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-11T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-10-12T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-13T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-10-14T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-15T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-10-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-17T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-10-18T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-19T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-10-20T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-21T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-10-22T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-10-24T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-25T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-10-26T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-27T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-10-28T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-29T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-10-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-10-31T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-11-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-11-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-11-03T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-11-04T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-11-05T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-11-06T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-11-07T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-11-08T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-11-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-11-10T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-11-11T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-11-12T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-11-13T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-11-14T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-11-15T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-11-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-11-17T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-11-18T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-11-19T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-11-20T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-11-21T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-11-22T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-11-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-11-24T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-11-25T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-11-26T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-11-27T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-11-28T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-11-29T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-11-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-12-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-03T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-12-04T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-05T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-12-06T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-07T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-12-08T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-12-10T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-11T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-12-12T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-13T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-12-14T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-15T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-12-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-17T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-12-18T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-19T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-12-20T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-21T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-12-22T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-12-24T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-25T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-12-26T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-27T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-12-28T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-29T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2004-12-30T00:00:00.000000000', '2004-12-31T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-02T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-03T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-04T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-05T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-06T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-07T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-08T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-10T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-11T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-12T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-13T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-14T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-15T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-16T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-17T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-18T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-19T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-20T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-21T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-22T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-23T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-24T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-25T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-26T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-27T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-28T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-29T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-01-30T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-01-31T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-02-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-02-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-02-03T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-02-04T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-02-05T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-02-06T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-02-07T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-02-08T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-02-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-02-10T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-02-11T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-02-12T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-02-13T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-02-14T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-02-15T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-02-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-02-17T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-02-18T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-02-19T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-02-20T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-02-21T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-02-22T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-02-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-02-24T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-02-25T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-02-26T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-02-27T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-02-28T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-03-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-03-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-03-03T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-03-04T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-03-05T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-03-06T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-03-07T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-03-08T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-03-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-03-10T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-03-11T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-03-12T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-03-13T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-03-14T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-03-15T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-03-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-03-17T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-03-18T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-03-19T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-03-20T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-03-21T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-03-22T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-03-23T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-03-24T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-03-25T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-03-26T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-03-27T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-03-28T00:00:00.000000000', '2005-03-29T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2005-03-30T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

2. `values`

```
values = np.array([7.70072076e+00, 1.15550154e+01, 2.52179418e+01, 1.55478327e+01,
       2.59781549e+01, 2.34152693e+01, 1.79109624e+01, 1.19977931e+01,
       1.00978354e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 4.63780341e+00, 9.86850318e+00,
       5.25415761e+00, 3.91471839e+00, 1.96036085e+01, 1.90064540e+01,
       1.11661406e+01, 2.25606837e+01, 6.00817101e+00, 1.69457231e+01,
       1.12589495e+01, 1.70272436e+01, 8.52431208e+00, 6.99124111e+00,
       1.34710377e+01, 1.40938799e+01, 1.38007694e+01, 2.41116309e+01,
       1.48877005e+01, 1.34417599e+01, 1.10949287e+01, 1.76228695e+01,
       2.00311967e+01, 1.34366201e+01, 2.59325445e+01, 2.14892189e+01,
       1.46289504e-01, 2.58948139e+01, 1.27299791e+01, 8.53511688e+00,
       1.95477776e+01, 7.75086195e+00, 1.08907403e+01, 1.21731987e+01,
       3.32295294e-01, 2.33457880e+01, 1.03636754e+00, 2.51652898e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 2.36290467e+01, 7.49552335e+00, 5.31544824e+00,
       1.52790873e+00, 1.81752126e+01, 4.13123845e+00, 1.31874512e+01,
       6.01649464e-01, 9.40022796e+00, 2.04857146e+01, 7.54955426e+00,
       4.20621914e+00, 8.00308549e+00, 2.24401814e+00, 1.45324028e+01,
       1.45319574e+01, 7.99542387e+00, 2.76623390e+01, 1.07801930e+01,
       3.16076758e+00, 2.08360200e+01, 1.29046245e+01, 1.39387913e+01,
       1.20802721e+00, 1.46970620e+01, 2.54739344e+00, 2.61452965e+00,
       2.56090636e+01, 2.41717369e+00, 7.54546906e+00, 2.12478859e+01,
       1.19155216e+01, 4.63542198e+00, 7.71845492e+00, 1.56085474e+01,
       1.86042955e+01, 2.05600909e+01, 2.06061635e+01, 1.34498937e+00,
       2.32473478e+01, 3.79213708e+00, 4.41185690e+00, 4.76466781e+00,
       3.03566769e+00, 1.40809127e+01, 1.40129436e+01, 1.85373554e+01,
       1.97763783e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.50543144e+01, 1.39111993e+01,
       2.05928796e+01, 1.66687205e+00, 2.31263408e+00, 9.75572291e+00,
       2.07017149e+01, 1.58974488e+01, 1.16193468e+01, 7.27507123e+00,
       2.96885028e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 4.52040888e+00, 1.02263017e+01,
       1.03136977e+01, 8.25899582e-01, 5.03786892e+00, 1.68507230e+01,
       1.00213081e+01, 6.38183248e+00, 5.71099386e+00, 1.38144686e+01,
       7.15521205e+00, 5.94458881e+00, 2.62194930e+00, 1.94945780e+01,
       9.33201928e+00, 1.36677680e+01, 1.56902998e+01, 5.37752133e+00,
       3.58222494e+00, 1.00110565e+01, 9.00501132e+00, 6.06534711e+00,
       8.93813028e+00, 1.17667303e+01, 1.51834064e+01, 5.38251677e+00,
       6.64119918e+00, 8.50995608e+00, 5.16653574e+00, 1.07122130e+01,
       9.18142490e+00, 7.79627403e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.03848055e+01, 1.08489897e+01,
       6.21303638e+00, 1.06653583e+01, 1.90092719e+01, 2.47118370e+01,
       6.07360133e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       7.20030534e-01, 2.49698890e+01, 2.13602459e-01, 2.45318682e+00,
       5.01041793e-01, 1.90137329e+01, 1.46071881e+01, 7.23347874e+00,
       1.95912745e+01, 3.58426756e+00, 9.51807936e+00, 4.36878079e-02,
       2.21128522e+01, 3.17686016e+01, 2.99007373e+01, 3.04031682e+01,
       2.02257518e+01, 1.86238389e+01, 2.76588079e+01, 2.21848903e+01,
       1.07687429e+01, 2.37335606e+01, 1.66929890e+01, 2.35181666e+01,
       1.69985338e+00, 2.83520296e+01, 2.16374393e+01, 2.05611237e+01,
       3.59128604e+01, 3.87838765e+01, 7.45223977e+00, 3.03020402e+01,
       1.86921895e+01, 2.09489534e+01, 3.58149879e+01, 1.27630888e+01,
       4.10551490e+01, 5.58532492e+00, 1.84476961e+01, 3.14587052e+01,
       3.25132686e+01, 6.31785153e+00, 3.46112066e+01, 5.39397069e+00,
       3.04035074e+01, 2.48492473e+01, 9.79893327e+00, 1.84628427e+01,
       1.86888600e+01, 3.67012881e+01, 3.41793981e+01, 3.99801672e+01,
       3.93846918e+01, 2.92138714e+01, 2.16493085e+01, 1.19923666e+01,
       2.06220580e+01, 9.22929337e+00, 1.21253861e+01, 2.39722270e+01,
       2.83720115e+01, 1.31777736e+01, 2.25567754e+01, 1.26539722e+01,
       2.90462533e+01, 3.71084505e+01, 4.30259275e+01, 4.07509318e+01,
       2.35128070e+01, 3.53533807e+01, 1.70285172e+01, 3.30286511e+01,
       2.38847906e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.52662806e+01, 1.69363015e+01,
       2.46401968e+01, 2.11388967e+01, 1.02503617e+01, 5.87485942e+00,
       6.58417043e-01, 1.59571398e+01, 1.38180476e+01, 7.53667991e+00,
       1.63162834e+01, 2.87401191e+01, 3.24826676e+01, 2.11112348e+01,
       2.22729622e+01, 2.08574081e+01, 1.04833067e+01, 6.79199822e+00,
       2.35733811e+01, 3.51793514e+01, 6.80932152e+00, 2.09290927e+01,
       4.35239938e+00, 6.31846749e+00, 4.59065600e+00, 2.83986563e+01,
       3.62887793e+01, 1.80637687e+01, 1.35552655e+01, 1.67298455e+00,
       3.12957390e+01, 3.81211895e+01, 2.81783440e+01, 5.73997181e+00,
       2.58828941e+00, 2.45794860e+01, 8.26224226e+00, 8.32910394e+00,
       2.67829527e+01, 2.14388670e+01, 2.39131033e+01, 1.28893395e+01,
       6.80103296e+00, 5.90787620e+00, 1.33425236e+01, 1.14569906e+01,
       6.92987448e+00, 4.11646860e+00, 3.02049801e+01, 3.70180538e+01,
       3.27249529e+01, 1.58443540e+01, 3.41710006e-01, 2.36869973e+00,
       1.96053557e+01, 1.01010941e+01, 3.89427977e+01, 1.87978068e+01,
       2.53674880e+01, 1.35991975e+01, 8.33476273e+00, 7.39297656e+00,
       2.26704228e+01, 3.81890746e+01, 3.92587785e+00, 3.30023774e+01,
       2.36791818e+01, 2.75009903e+01, 5.09154447e+00, 5.32452541e+00,
       1.74513700e+01, 1.83963763e+01, 3.12658501e+01, 3.99468412e+01,
       2.12089935e+01, 1.39061695e+01, 1.91288989e+01, 1.30272091e+01,
       1.36074910e+01, 3.69017354e+01, 2.93510937e+01, 2.40498501e+01,
       1.24911778e+00, 2.58514096e+01, 1.39207610e+01, 3.66927101e+01,
       4.65986156e+00, 2.41432470e+01, 1.87374470e+01])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick approach could be the following:

```
months = times.astype('datetime64[M]').astype(int) % 12 + 1
print([(month, values[months==month].mean()) for month in set(months)])

years = times.astype('datetime64[Y]').astype(int) + 19707
print([(year, values[years==year].mean()) for year in set(years)])
```

**FOLLOW UP**

Following up on your comment:

```
yearmonths=years*100 + months

print([(ym, values[yearmonths==ym].mean()) for ym in set(yearmonths)])
```

Comment: Sorry, my question must have been not clearly defined. I meant that I want to eventually have a single array, containing the average value for each month - year combination. For example, 2001-01 and 2002-01 would have different average values